# Store serverside javascript functions in MongoDB using Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I've been trying to store server side functions in MongoDB (from the client side)

I'm trying this, from the examples:

```
db.system.js.save({_id: "sum",
              value: function (x, y) { return x + y; }});
```

But that does not work. I am using Mongoose, so I don't know if it has a wrapper around the plain Mongo DB object.

Comment: What if you encapsulate the value into a string?

Comment: Problem is that db.system.js does not exist.

Comment: It should...What is the exact error message you get from trying to run that command above?

Comment: That db.system is undefined. Mind you: this is on the client side, inside a node.js program. So not in a mongo shell. I *can* use db.eval.

Comment: It should allow you connect to the system.js collection through node much the same way, I am no genuis when it comes to node.js

Answer (score 5):

Use the [mongoose-function](https://github.com/aheckmann/mongoose-function) plugin to add function support to mongoose.

Then create a schema and force its collection name:

```
new Schema({ value: Function }, { collection: 'system.js' })
```